# Drawing multiple bars per date

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have an array of data, each element consists of a date and some information to display. I'm unable to draw the barchart.

I tried multiple solutions, yet no one worked so far.

The data is an array with the following contents.

```
{ metric1: 10,
  metric2: 20,
  metric3: 30,
  timestamp: a Date object }
```

Now I want to draw the metrics next to each other on the x-axis with the date as index.

```
    const x = d3.scaleTime()
      .rangeRound([0, width]);

    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    const z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%a %H:%M'));

    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
```

This is afaik correct, but now comes the tricky part. I need to add the domains. Furthermore, I have colors and abstracted the correct keys from the data.

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date));
y.domain(max of metrics);
```

However, the domain of z is not so clear to me, only using 'scaleBand' I'm able to use the bandwidth() to make sure bars are ligned up to the corresponding date.

I tried several guides and examples. But they all leave me hanging on constructing the graph correctly. Currently I can only see the axis being drawn.

What I can do is e.g.:

```
    var legend = svg => {
      const g = svg
          .attr("transform", `translate(${width},0)`)
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
          .attr("font-size", 10)
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
        .join("g")
          .attr("transform", (d, i) => `translate(0,${i * 20})`);

      g.append("rect")
          .attr("x", -19)
          .attr("width", 19)
          .attr("height", 19)
          .attr("fill", color);

      g.append("text")
          .attr("x", -24)
          .attr("y", 9.5)
          .attr("dy", "0.35em")
          .text(d => d);
    }
```

The above works perfectly in order to draw a legend with the correct keys and colors. The bars however are not showing up.

can somebody point me  to a good guide?

Comment: Basically you can't use scaleTime for the x-axis when grouping. The solution was to use something like: d3.Timeformat to parse a date into a string (intervals need to be similar tho for the visualisation to make sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can't use scaleTime for the x-axis when grouping. The solution was to use something like: d3.Timeformat to parse a date into a string (intervals need to be similar tho for the visualisation to make sense)